# Custom view with a tiled texture and a mask

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have an Android app with an image view of a wooden panel like the following. 
[image: Current panel]

The left, right, and bottom are flush with the edges of the screen, and the top is located at a certain point near the center of the screen. There are some views underneath, partially covered by the curved portion, and some other smaller views (buttons and such) on top. The image (a .PNG) has some slight chamfer designs at the top that I'd like to keep.

I'm looking for ways to speed up drawing to avoid skipping frames, and possibly also reduce the size of assets. I am wondering if it is possible and/or advisable to replace this with a custom view that first tiles the entire view with a wood pattern, then uses a mask to make the top portion transparent, then adds a semi-transparent layer to replicate the chamfer.

[image]
[image]

Question 1: is this possible? 
Question 2: is it a good idea, in terms of performance? Will the benefits outweigh costs like the extra overdraw?

Comment: `Is it possible?` Probably. To be verified. `Is it a good ... performance?` Well, I wouldn't bet on that, since the computational costs would be higher than simply rendering an image.

Comment: @Fantômas I thought that tiling a texture would be cheaper than scaling a large image to fit the dimensions of the screen.

Comment: Scaling and tiling should be comparable in terns of performance. What's expensive is the masking.